# how to redirect custom html site to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

How to Redirect

**Old Link:**
 http://www.astrokapoor.com/products/gems/gemstones/ruby-manik-new-burmees/ (this is custom php/html site)

**New Link-** http://astrokapoor.com/en/ruby-manik-gemstone/  (this is wordpress site link)

I used below code but no success

```
RewriteRule ^/products/gems/gemstones/ruby-manik-new-burmees /en/ruby-manik-gemstone [L,R=301]
```

Comment: In .htaccess context, the path the RewriteRule checks against never starts with a slash.

Comment: Try with php redirection in index.php

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume both the source and the target reside in the different virtualhosts and that you are defining this in VirtualHost context. Let's also assume you are the admin of the site and you have no reason to define this in .htaccess context.

All you need is a Redirect directive in the source virtualhost:

```
Redirect /products/gems/gemstones/ruby-manik-new-burmees/ http://astrokapoor.com/en/ruby-manik-gemstone/
```

This will redirect /products/gems/gemstones/ruby-manik-new-burmees/ and all subpaths from it to the new url, such if someone requests:

Host: www.astrokapoor.com
GET /products/gems/gemstones/ruby-manik-new-burmees/something

they will get redirected to:
http://astrokapoor.com/en/ruby-manik-gemstone/something

Note: Redirect belongs to mod_alias. In such simple redirection cases you should avoid mod_rewrite. Use mod_rewrite only when you have no other choice.

Comment: Great sir, Your answer helped me alot to understand redirect concept.

Comment: pls also suggest me how to redirect  urls:- astrokapoor.co/sunsign/aquarius%4027.html (old Url) TO New Url :- astrokapoor.com/en/Aquarius-sunsign

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^products/gems/gemstones/ruby-manik-new-burmees/$ http://astrokapoor.com/en/ruby-manik-gemstone/ [L]


RewriteRule ^sunsign/aquarius%4027.html/$ http://www.astrokapoor.com/en/Aquarius-sunsign/ [L]
```

Comment: pls also suggest me how to redirect below urls:- http://www.astrokapoor.co/sunsign/aquarius%4027.html  (old Url)   TO New Url :- http://www.astrokapoor.com/en/Aquarius-sunsign/

Comment: Use this. It will work.

RewriteRule ^sunsign/aquarius%4027.html$ http://www.astrokapoor.com/en/Aquarius-sunsign/ [L]

Comment: no sir its not working, i used this code RewriteRule ^sunsign/aquarius%4027.html$ http://www.astrokapoor.com/en/Aquarius-sunsign/ [L]

Comment: I have updated the code please try that,still it is not working then you can use https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/ plugin for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your old page html page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://astrokapoor.com/en/ruby-manik-gemstone/" />
```

Comment: sir i have morethan 500 pages ..pls suggest me any easy way to do this..anyway thanks for your valuable response

Comment: Do you have not some header or configuration file which will be included in all files. Further, you can use .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

By using [simple redirect plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/) You can set your redirect links easily by define each URL to match each page.